# Changing a value in an html tag using RegEx

Tags: php, html, regex

As a regex newbie, this is frustrating me - all help appreciated.
I have something like this:

```
<img src="https://jdfsdf.dsfsdf.sdfsd/upload/sm/dsfsdf/sdfsdf/sdfdsf.jpg" style="..." id="..">
```

I want it to be:

```
<img src="https://jdfsdf.dsfsdf.sdfsd/upload/lg/dsfsdf/sdfsdf/sdfdsf.jpg" style="..." id="..">
```

Basically, changing the /sm/ to /lg/.
I'd like to do this via RegEx in PHP, and I'm using http://www.phpliveregex.com/ to test.

I could do this simply, but with less robustness, using a simple PHP str_replace - for the sake of this question I'd like to keep the answers using RegEx.

I have tried to use a look-behind, like below:

```
(?<=<img src.+upload\/)sm
```

This obviously doesn't work, but the code below does match to the desired point.

```
<img src.+upload\/
```

I'm stumped.  Any assistance or links to a decent tutorial that covers this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to capture your result into a group. Your regex will look like this:

```
(<img src.+upload/)(sm)([^>]+>)
```

As you can see you can capture groups by adding parentheses. Now it's just the matter of using these groups and replacing the values.

```
$string = '<img src="https://jdfsdf.dsfsdf.sdfsd/upload/sm/dsfsdf/sdfsdf/sdfdsf.jpg" style="..." id="..">';
$pattern = '/(<img src.+upload/)(sm)([^>]+>)/i';
$replacement = '$1lg$3';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Try this regex out at http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: Is that replacement pattern supposed to be '$1lg$3'?  Great answer, btw.

Comment: Accepted this answer, but it does need an escape in the $pattern declaration: $pattern = '/(<img src.+upload\/)(sm)([^>]+>)/i';  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
preg_replace('@(<img[^>]+http[^\'">]+)/sm/@i', '$1/lg/', $str1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use str_replace for this. Regexp for this task is very hard.